# How to create such a diagram in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create this diagram with Chart.js.

Challenges:

- As you see on the x-axis are categories. I want the point to be placed in the middle.
- I want the value to be on top of the point.

[image]

My code so far:

```
        new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['Buy', 'Sell'],
            datasets:
                [
                    ...grid.pairs.map(pair => {
                        return {
                            data: [pair.buyPrice, pair.sellPrice],
                            borderColor: '#0d6efd',
                            backgroundColor: '#0d6efd',
                            pointRadius: [3, 5],
                        }
                    }),
                    {
                        label: 'Market Price',
                        data: [grid.marketPrice, grid.marketPrice],
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        backgroundColor: 'red',
                    }
                ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                },
                y: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Price in Euro'
                    },
                }
            },
        }
    })
```

May I get some help with this?

Comment: You just need to set a few options in chart.js, like [`offset: true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html#common-options-to-all-cartesian-axes) for x axis to center the x positions in the categories, and [`beginAtZero: true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-options) for the y axis. If you want the numbers in the drawing to actually appear on the chart, you have to use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/), see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0aetfh4/) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making this a `bar` chart, the data points are in the center of each bar, as requested. The individual data series should be of `type: 'line'`

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const grid = {
  marketPrice: 12,
  pairs: [{
      buyPrice: 12,
      sellPrice: 3
    },
    {
      buyPrice: 16,
      sellPrice: 6
    },
    {
      buyPrice: 17,
      sellPrice: 2
    },

  ]

}
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Buy', 'Sell'],
    datasets: [
      ...grid.pairs.map((pair, index) => {
        return {
          label: 'Series ' + index,
          type: 'line',
          data: [pair.buyPrice, pair.sellPrice],
          borderColor: '#0d6efd',
          backgroundColor: '#0d6efd',
          pointRadius: [3, 5],
        }
      }),
      {
        type: 'line',
        label: 'Market Price',
        data: [grid.marketPrice, grid.marketPrice],
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {},
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Price in Euro'
        },
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. Sincerely I was expecting a solution with "type: categories" as seen on few places. But actually this didnt lead to the solution